# Fazer v-for somente com número

Tags: vue.js

É possível fazer um `v-for` utilizando apenas um número total?

Exemplo:

Eu passaria uma variável com valor `10`, ele faria um loop de 1 a 10, tipo o exemplo em JS abaixo:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= num_parcelas; i++){
      mostrar += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `v-for` com um range. Por exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="range" class="demo">
  <select>
    <option v-for="n in 10" :value="n">{{ n }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script>
  new Vue({ el: '#range' })
</script>
```

Veja na [documentação](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range).